# SVN sub-changeset commit?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, ankhsvn

I am using AnkhSVN in Visual Studio 2008 as a source control solution.  I love to check out, edit and then re-commit partial changes as a way to ensure I never lose incremental progress.  Is there anything smaller than a changeset that will allow me to check-in incremental changes as a way to ensure I don't lose them/overwrite them between changesets without having me creating 20 changesets in the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in SVN, but what you can do is layer GIT in front of SVN.  That way you can make a ton of local changes without having to push them up to SVN.  It is also useful in shops which don't make proper use of branching, you can isolate yourself from the pollution of mainline.  It also adds the ability to shelve changes in case you wnat to put some changes aside for later.  Check out

http://blog.tsunanet.net/2007/07/learning-git-svn-in-5min.html

Comment: git also gives you the ability to commit only part of the changes in your sandbox (not just files but actual changes) which gives you a lot of control. You can check out the `-q` option to `git add` for more information.